# Lightswitch App Authentication/Authorization after database change

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a working Lightswitch app, using Forms Authentication.
I have had to point this existing app at a new database, and now my username is not assigned the admin role anymore, and of course that means I cannot access the Roles and Users menu options in order to make myself an administrator.

Perhaps I missed a step in prep'ing the new database:

1) For the new database, and applied the usual aspnet_regsql stuff.
2) I DTS'd the data from each of the aspnet_ tables from the old database to the new database.

I would have expected that if there is a problem with this I would get the error that my username does not exist at all.  Instead it is allowing me to log in, but it's just that in my app, my username is not associated with the Admin role anymore.  Why is that?  I have confirmed through SQL queries that the user and roles setup in the new database is identical to the old database.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried publishing the app again, but make sure to select "Yes, create an Application Administrator" and specify your username?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well...but it made no difference.  But this gives me an idea to try publishing it and specifying a new username for this Application Administrator setting...will let you know how that turns out...

Comment: Interestingly re-publishing with a new username as the Administrator indeed allows a log in of that new username, with full admin privileges. And alas, looking at the Roles view it shows my old username as belonging to the Administrator role.  Yet that old username logs in and is NOT granted admin privileges. Weird.

Comment: Oh wow...somehow that deploy with a new username as the admin seemed to solve the problem!  Now the log on of my OLD username has admin privileges again! - @bigelowr make your comment an answer and I'll accept it as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try publishing the app again, but make sure to select "Yes, create an Application Administrator" and specify your username.

Comment: See comments to the original question